# Which order of adjectives is correct?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-order

1. She is a well-developed, tall, young woman.
2. She is a tall, young, well-developed woman.

In the sentences, which order of adjectives is correct? I'd like to know the rule for placing various adjectives.

Comment: I'd say neither. My preference would be tall, well-developed, young.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [standard order](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/ordering-multiple-adjectives/), I guess (just search "English adjective order" for examples):

```
What the adjective expresses    Examples
------------------------------- ------------------------------
Quantity                        four, ten, a few, several
Value/Opinion                   delicious, charming, beautiful
Size                            tall, tiny, huge
Temperature                     hot, cold
Age                             old, young, new, 14-year-old
Shape                           square, round
Color                           red, purple, green
Origin                          Swedish, Victorian, Chinese
Material                        glass, silver, wooden
```

The only hard rules are:

- Determiners first, always, this includes articles, possessive pronouns, etc.
- Quanitity should *always* precede anything else.  I think in these cases they are technically a type of determiner.  "I had blue four cars" sounds wrong.

Also it's a good idea to have color and material close to the noun, but this won't kill a sentence if you don't do it:

> I have four blue tall boxes ("I have four tall blue boxes" sounds a bit better but "four blue tall boxes" doesn't sound wrong.)

Apart from the above, you can simply choose what sounds best or rolls off your tongue the easiest.

Comment: See also [What is the rule for adjective order?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1155/2490) on ELU.